# how to upload photo to sql using json wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am creating WCF for an iphone app. i want to know how to upload photo to the sql using json wcf any idea?this is the process how to connect it to the sql?

```
 public class TestService : ITestService
       {
           [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile?fileName={fileName}")]
           public string UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
           {
               //save file
               string absFileName = "";
               try
               {
                     absFileName = string.Format("{0}\\FileUpload\\{1}"
                                           , AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                                           , Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0,6)  + ".jpg");

                  // string fld = @"h:\root\home\amrmk185-001\www\publish\WCFService\FileUpload\" + fileName;
                   //System.IO.File.Create(absFileName);
                     using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(absFileName, FileMode.Create))
                   {
                       fileContents.CopyTo(fs);
                       fileContents.Close();
                   }
                   return "Upload OK";
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
                   return "FAIL ==> " + ex.Message + "   " + absFileName;
               }
           }
```

Comment: Did you post the correct method? or are you downloading an image to the iPhone

Comment: i dont no how this what i did for getting data but i dont no how to use post for getting uploaded photo

Comment: Where is code doing the actual upload?